# Directly Record Screen on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

OK so I want to record the screen of a Mac directly to a .mov or .m4v. I've taken a look at Son of Grab from Apple, but I would prefer not to deal with screenshots and individual images and just work with video.

I thought there should be something in QTKit but I can't find it. I know this can be done in OpenGL, but 1) I don't know how and 2) I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Just to elaborate, I am recording from iSight using QTCaptureDeviceInput and (obviously a QTDevice) because I need to solution to work on Snow Leopard.

It seems like there should be a way to just target the screen as the input device for QTMediaTypeVideo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AVFoundation to do screen recording on the Mac. It's only available on 10.7 though.

Comment: Ok I give up. Every solution I find for using OpenGL seems to lead to a broken link on Apple's site. How would I do this using AVFoundation? A link to a sample would be awesome.

Comment: Ok so I ended making the app Lion only for now, but this really isn't the cleanest solution imo

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGDisplayCreateImage/CGDisplayCreateImageFromRect APIs (10.6+) to obtain still images of screen and then making a movie out of them.

I'm not sure how good will be the performance though.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when faced with the question, will it be fast enough or not, just give it a try. Do a quick test by gabbing frame after frame say 1000 times and time it. CGDisplayCreateImageFromRect is not that hard to call at all. I have called it for single screen shots of the whole screen when the mouse was clicked, and it hardly slowed my mac down (only a basic dual core machine).

Apple has two samples showing the main two ways this can be done: :-

ScreenSnapshot
SonOfGrab

It would be easy to modify these to do it say 1000 times in a loop!